# Using AudioPlaybackCapture API in MediaRecorder

Tags: android-mediarecorder, audiorecord, mediamuxer

I use media recorder to record the screen and I'm wondering if I could use the [AudioPlaybackCapture API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/playback-capture) to stream the system audio in? I know mediarecorder is a high level API and MediaMuxer would give me more controls but the app already uses a lot of mediarecorder API and there is no way turning back.

I have tried to set up the `AudioRecord` and use its `getAudioSource()` to set the audio source in media recorder like below but it failed and the getAudioSource() returns the ID of r_submix which requires the app to be system app.

```
int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(32000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT) * 2;

        AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration audioConfig =
                new AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration.Builder(mMediaProjection)
                        .addMatchingUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                        .addMatchingUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_UNKNOWN)
                        .addMatchingUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                        .build();

        AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat.Builder()
                .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
                .setSampleRate(32000)
                .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO)
                .build();


        AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord.Builder()
                .setAudioPlaybackCaptureConfig(audioConfig)
                .setAudioFormat(audioFormat)
                .setBufferSizeInBytes(bufferSize)
                .build();

mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(recorder.getAudioSource());
```

tl;dr: I'm looking for a solution to use [AudioPlaybackCapture](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/playback-capture) API along with mediarecorder to capture the internal audio.

Comment: Please, tell if you managed to record audio.

Comment: Were you able to resolve issue, i am facing same issue